# REST - Jetty 9 and Jersey 2.6 Multipart file upload

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I'm trying to create an api to write (upload) a file with `Jetty 9.4.7` and `Jersey 2.26`.

The api is structured like this: `/api/write`

I am initializing the server in `App.java` which is in `com.rest.app` package. The resource file `FileUploadResource.java` is in `com.rest.res` package.

Here's the `App.java` class:

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server(8500);

    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(FileUploadResource.class);
    resourceConfig.packages("com.rest.res");
    resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(contextHandler);

    ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = contextHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/api/*");
    jerseyServletHolder.setInitOrder(0);


    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Stopping server....");
        server.destroy();
    }

}
```

}

and the here's the `FileUploadResource.java`:

```
@Path("/")
public class FileUploadResource {
    @POST
    @Path("write")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response write(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition) {

        // upload file
        // do something

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I send any request, I get this error:

```
WARNING: Attempt to release request processing resources has failed for a request.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
```

Here's `pom.xml` dependency tree:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your pom:

```
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
```